# show that $ker(T) ⊆ (M ∩ N) × (M ∩ N)$ and $ker(T) ∼= M ∩ N$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Suppose $ M, N $ are subspaces of $ V$. Define $T : M × N → V$ by $T((x, y)) = x + y.$

I proved that $T$ is a linear map. Now I'm trying to show that $ker(T) ⊆ (M ∩ N) × (M ∩ N)$.

Here's my proof so far:

Suppose $(x,y)∈ker(T)$.

So $T(x,y) = x+y=0∈V$. (since $T$ maps to $V$)

And $ker(T)$ is contained in $M × N$, so $(x,y)∈M × N$.

So, $x∈M$ and $y∈N$, and $x+y = 0$, then $x∈N$ and $y∈M$.

Since $x,y∈M$ and $x,y∈M$, we have that $x,y∈(M ∩ N)$.

So we can write $x∈(M ∩ N) and y∈(M ∩ N) $

So,  $x∈(M ∩ N) × y∈(M ∩ N) $, by definition of cartesian product.

So, $(x,y)∈(M ∩ N) × (M ∩ N) $.

Thus, $ker(T)$ is contained in $(M ∩ N) × (M ∩ N)$.

I'm also trying this problem: Show that $ker(T) ∼= M ∩ N$.

I need to give an isomorphism. So, I know I need to prove it's injective, surjective and linear. So far I have some thoughts on this one. To prove it's injective I was thinking that I need to show that $ker(T)$ is in $M ∩ N$. For surjective, I'm stuck. For linear, I thought that it was given since $T$ is linear map, but I'm not sure if it's enough to say that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problematic line doesn't even make sense, but if you meant that $(0,0)$ is the only element in the kernel, it's not true in general.

So we have $x\in M,\ y\in N$ and $x+y=0$.
Then $x\in N$ and $y\in M$ as well, can you see why?

For the other question, verify that the projection $\ker T\to M\cap N,\ (x,y)\mapsto x$ is an isomorphism (e.g. find its inverse).

Comment: Is " $x∈N$ and $y∈M$ as well " because $x=0-y$, so, $x=-y$, and by closure of multiplication, $-y∈M$. And the same goes for $x$?

Comment: I fixed some stuff, does it seem like a good proof now?

Comment: Yes. Have you obtained the inverse for the isomorphism?

Comment: No, I'm still stuck on that one. Will having an inverse prove that it's injective, surjective, and linear all at once?

Comment: Not the linear part. But the projection is easily seen to be linear.

Comment: I think I can prove it's a linear map, but I first need to figure out the inverse.

Comment: Which element of $\ker T$ has $x\in M\cap N$ as the first coordinate?

Comment: Would it be $M∩N →kerT, x↦(x,y)$? I feel like that isn't completely right.

Comment: It might be right if you tell what $y$ is for a given $x$.

Comment: Is $y=x$? Sorry for all the questions, I just really want to understand this all but I'm not really getting how the isomorphism works and how I can prove the inverse.

Comment: Well.. you want $(x,y)\in\ker T$ where $T$ is still the addition on $M\times N$. So... given $x\in M\cap N$, then what is $y$?

Comment: $y=0?$ Or $y∈M∩N$

Comment: You already performed this simple algebraic operation: if $x+y=0$ it means $y=-x$. Does it ring a bell?